# can we make the function, it's integral is cantor function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm curious about making cantor function by integrating function f(x)

cantor function starts with f(0) = 0 and ends with f(1) = 1

when we define  E = {x $\in $ X: f(x) > 0}  and |E| is measure of E

we can think $\int_{|E|} f(x) = 1 $

but by definition of cantor set, |E| converge to 0

so we can think function f(x) can be uncountably many rectangle, which height deverge

someone tells me this is not function but distribution

then what is accurate definition of function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be the Cantor function.  There is no integrable function $f$ such that $F(x)=c+\int_0^{x} f(t)dt$. In fact this represenntation is possible iff $F$ is absolutely continuous whereas the Cantor function is singular.

Comment: thank you so much! I have a question of your statement. what is "our function" mean? is that f or F? is that means cantor function is singular so not absolutely continuous?

Comment: @kkugosu Edited.

Answer (score 2):

To get the Cantor function $F$ by integration, we cannot integrate a function (as shown by Kavi).  But there is a **measure** $\mu$ so that
$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \;d\mu
$$
for all $x$.  We may say that $\mu$ is the derivative of $F$ in the weak sense.

Some day you may study Schwartz distributions, or generalized functions, where you see this and much more.  For example, the derivative of $\mu$ is not even a measure, it is something more exotic.